# Term store not found and the Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available

Tags: managed-metadata-service

this weekend end something happened and I cannt use the managed metadata service.

The error I have is:

```
The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or Managed Metadata Web Service may not have been started. Please Contact your Administrator.
```

The first error that I see in the ULS log related to my problem are:

```
    Failed to get term store for proxy 'MMS for Content Hub'. Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.    
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.XmlDataReader.GetDateTime(String name)    
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.SharedTermStore.Initialize(IDataReader dataReader, Guid termStoreIdValue, Boolean fromPersistedData)    
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.SharedTermStore..ctor(IDataReader dataReader, Guid termStoreId, Boolean fromPersistedData)    
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.DataAccessManager.GetTermStoreData(MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy sharedServiceProxy, Boolean& partitionCreated)
The Managed Metadata Service 'MMS for Content Hub' is inaccessible.
```

The service is startedbut I have :

```
The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or Managed Metadata Web Service may not have been started. Please Contact your Administrator.
```

I have tried based (on other posts with similar problems):

- Stopping and restarting a new Metadata Service.
- an iisreset.
- Checked permissions on the users who runs  the application pool and
  they are fine

The sites that use term store give me the following error

```
Constructing CachedExceptionData with OriginalUtcTime=09/26/2016 08:52:56, OriginalCorrelationId=f47da79d-eca6-404e-1e1a-c62cb218a54e: System.InvalidOperationException: TermStore not found
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.TaxonomyNavigationCache.CachedTermSet.Load(TaxonomySession taxonomySession, Int32 navigationLcid, SPSite contextSite, Guid contextWebId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.TaxonomyNavigationCache.CachedTermSet.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadIfNotAlreadyLoaded>b__0()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.LoadableLruCachedObject.LoadIfNotAlreadyLoaded(Action loadMethodCall)
```

Is there anything else I could try?

**EDIT:**
If I create a new Managed Metadata Service it gets created and it is shown
as started in the Central Admin/Service Applications but when I click 
on it it doesn't appear in the drop down with the Available Service Applications and again the message "The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available.

```
The Application Pool or Managed Metadata Web Service may not have been started. Please Contact your Administrator.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just renamed the service db and then renamed it back to the original name and it worked.

I got the hint here : [The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/67761779-6da4-4ab3-af53-6f3235f44428/the-managed-metadata-service-or-connection-is-currently-not-available?forum=sharepointadmin)